# Is there an easy way to trippel integrate a function when the region is a pyramid?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

My task is this;

Calculate: $$\iiint\limits_{A} \left(3y^2 - 3z\right)dA.$$

When $A$ is the region contained within the coordinate planes and the plane $P :3x + 2y - z = 6.$

My work so far:

Setting different variables to zero we obtain that the $P$ intersects the coordinate axis at $x = 2, y = 3, z = -6$. We can then draw the conclusion from the facts given that $A$ must be a pyramid with a three sided base. On a side note, the volume of this is $\frac{bh}{3} = \frac{(2*3*0.5)*6}{3} = 6$. I've set this one up as follows:$$\int\limits_0^2\int\limits_0^3\int_P^0 \left(3y^2 - 3z\right)dzdydx.$$

But this gets messy fast, and since this is one of my assignments i'm hoping for a shortcut method. Any help would be of value and don't calculate it out as i would have the pleasure of doing that myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the upper limit on the $y$ integration should be $(6-3x)/2$ instead of $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the volume, you just need the average value of the integrand, and for that it's enough to know that the coordinate values are weighted quadratically with the distance from their maximal value. Thus the average of $y^2$ is

$$
3^2\cdot\frac{\int_0^1(1-\xi)^2\xi^2\mathrm d\xi}{\int_0^1\xi^2\mathrm d\xi}
$$

and the average of $z$ is

$$
-6\cdot\frac{\int_0^1(1-\zeta)\zeta^2\mathrm d\zeta}{\int_0^1\zeta^2\mathrm d\zeta}\;.
$$